# How to deep pick in another pick with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Now i have code like this:

```
var object = {
   a: 'a',
   b: 'b',
   c: {
       d: 'd'
   }
}
_.get(object).pick(['a', 'b']).value();
```

How to deep pick property 'd' like:

```
_.get(object).pick(['a', 'b', 'c.d']).value();
```

Comment: @OriDrori object with properties a, b and d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you insist in using Lodash, consider using the [_.get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) function:

```
_.get(object, 'c.d');
```

So, for the properties you want to get:

```js
const selectedProps = {
  ..._.pick(object, ['a', 'b']),
  _.get(object, 'c.d')
}
```

Comment: when trying to use _.get() inside _.pick() it drops exception 'Cannot convert object to primitive value'

Comment: @NikitaIskorkin It supposed to be used alone, without `_.pick`.

Comment: and how I can create a new object with properties i need?

Answer (score 4):

you can deep destructure without lodash :

```js
var object = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: {
      d: 'd'
  }
}

const { a, b, c :{ d }} = object;

console.log(a,b,d);

const obj = {a, b, d};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: it doesnt compose new object like _.pick

Comment: yes, but you can always build it `const obj = {a,b,d}`

Comment: This will only work with primitive values ... it not deep at all, only shallow

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `flatPick()` function. The function iterates the array of paths. and uses `_.get()` to get the value of the `path`, and `_.set()` to add the last part of the path as property on the result object:

```js
function flatPick(object, paths) {
  const o = {};

  paths.forEach(path => _.set(
    o,
    _.last(path.split('.')),
    _.get(object, path)
  ));

  return o;
}

var object = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: {
    d: 'd',
    e: {
      f: 'f'
    }
  }
};

var result = flatPick(object, ['a', 'b', 'c.d', 'c.e.f']);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can work for `lodash`:

```
function pickNested(object: Json, fields: string[]) {
    const shallowFields = fields.filter((field) => !field.includes('.'));
    const deepFields = fields.filter((field) => field.includes('.'));

    const initialValue = _.pick(object, shallowFields) as Json;

    return deepFields.reduce((output, field) => {
        const key = _.snakeCase(field);
        output[key] = _.get(object, field);
        return output;
    }, initialValue);
}
```

and:

```
const json = {
    id: '10',
    user: {
        email: 'david.i@example.com',
    },
};

const newData = pickNested(json, ['id', 'user.email']);
console.log('newData ->', newData);
/*
{
    id: '10',
    user_email: 'david.i@example.com',
};
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear from your question if you want just the values to be extracted destructuring might be an option. But if you just want to pick specific properties eg. 'd', and keep the original json structure as it is, then there is a trick.

```
JSON.stringify(object, ['c','d'], 0)
```

Result:

```
'{"c":{"d":"d"}}'
```

Good thing is it works for array or objects.

```json
x = {
 top1: 1, 
 top2: {
    level2: [
        { leaf1a: 'a', leaf1b: 'b'},
        {leaf2a:'2a', leaf2b: '2b'}
    ]
 }
}
```

With `JSON.stringify(x, ['level2','top2', 'leaf2a'], 0)`

Will result in below structure.

```json
{
 "top2": {
  "level2": [
   {},
   {
    "leaf2a": "2a"
   },
   {}
  ]
 }
}
```

Its not perfect as you can see empty child elements, I only use this for analyzing deep nested structure with lots of attributes at each level, even used it sometimes for logging necessary items in a program.